# Origin for six ways to make chitta pleasant

Tags: scripture, yoga

Consider the following six ways to achieve pleasant Chitta quickly

> 1. Ekantha vaso (Being alone)
> 2. Laghu bojanadi (Taking enough food)
> 3. Mounam (Maintaining silence)
> 4. Nirasa (Lessening desires)
> 5. Controlling indriyas
> 6. Controlling tongue

What is the origin of these methods? Who told it and which scripture contains it?